# Azure Active directory and adding PCs

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have an Office365 account with about 10 users. Do I need to setup a domain controller server(or VM) to add these machines to or can I simply use Azure and a cloud based version(a bit like JumpCloud(https://jumpcloud.com)

Answer (score 1):

No need to set up a domain controller to manage your Office365 accounts.

With a combination of JumpCloud and an SSO solution such as Bitium (one of JumpCloud's partners), you gain centralized management of your Office365 user accounts from one cloud-based location, and use those same accounts for the rest of your organization, whether on your desktops, servers, WiFi, or any LDAP client apps.